# how to get value of cf in javascript

Tags: javascript, coldfusion, coldfusion-8

I have the following code in cf and I want to alert out the values

```
......
......
<cfelse>

            <cfset val = structFind(request.session.prefs, key)>

            <cfquery name="insertPref" datasource="database">
            INSERT  INTO 
                `database`.`user` (
                    `cID`, 
                    `cliID`, 
                    `userID`, 
                    `userPID`, 
                    `value` 
                )
            SELECT 
                #request.cID#, 
                #request.cliID#, 
                #request.userID#, 
                `user`.`userPID`, 
                <cfqueryparam value="#preserveSingleQuotes(val)#"> 
            FROM 
                `database`.`user` 
            WHERE 
                `applicationID` = 1 

            AND 
                `name` = <cfqueryparam value="#preserveSingleQuotes(key)#"> 
            ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
                `value` = <cfqueryparam value="#preserveSingleQuotes(val)#"> 
            </cfquery>

        </cfif>

    </cfif>

</cfloop>
```

Any help will be appreciated

Comment: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/CFMLRef/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec22c24-6e9d.html

Comment: Why are you using preserveSingleQuotes() with cfqueryparam ..?

Comment: should use "list=true" in cfqueryparam instead of preservesinglequotes().

Comment: i dont have cf background. Can you tell me what do you mean by list = true?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would use myval due to the fact that val is a function to return an integer.

Did you try:

```
<cfoutput>
   <script type="text/javascript">
       alert("#myval#");
   </script>
</cfoutput>
```

Answer (score 3):

If you wanna convert CF value to Javascript value, use ToScript.

```
<cfset thisString="hello world">
<script type="text/javascript" language="JavaScript">
<cfoutput>
var #toScript(thisString, "jsVar")#;
</cfoutput>
</script>
```